# Ascii value different in PHP vs swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert 255 to ascii char, according to the tables and PHP it is a non breaking space, but in swift it gives 'ÿ' using:

```
let s = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(255)))
```

Would really appreciate some advice on this :)

Comment: What encoding does your PHP use? PHP's encoding may differ in context and environment. Swift uses Unicode and U+00FF definitely is LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS (ÿ).

Comment: Right, I thought so much! Thanks, so how would I get around this? Can I set the encoding?

Comment: Check your php.ini file and find settings named `encoding` or `charset`. By the way _extended ASCII_ is not an official specification, so there may be many extended ASCIIs in the world. ([The extended ASCII table](http://www.wendag.com/Computer/ascii_code.html)) If you cannot find an official name (for example IANA) of your encoding, you may need to make character mapping table by yourself.

Comment: thanks, it appears we're on UTF-8? In that case, is there any way to use that ASCII table?

Comment: UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding scheme, so you cannot make a single character (code point) from a single byte in UTF-8 byte sequence. And 255 is not a valid value in UTF-8.

Comment: What sort of input do you get from PHP side? Only one byte? Don't you get multiple bytes?

Comment: Hi! I get values from 0-255, which are run through chr() to give a value from http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: It's not clear enough, how your PHP code send such data to Swift side?

Comment: And PHP's `chr()` does not use such character table. It just digs out internal byte representation.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII only uses codes 0 to 127. Code points 128 to 255 are *not* part of ASCII -- but they may be assigned in other character encodings.

For example, Windows-1252 is a single-byte-per-codepoint encoding that agrees with ASCII on 0–127 and that maps code point 255 to `ÿ`. (Unicode also assigns codepoint 255 to `ÿ`.)

In Unicode (and also Windows-1252), character with decimal code point 160 is the non-breaking space:

```
let nbsp = String(UnicodeScalar(160))
```

Comment: Thanks, in that case, can you please advise how could I use the extended ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/) in Swift please?

Comment: Find the name of the character and then look up that character's code point in Unicode. This site lets you copy-and-paste them to aid you on your search: https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/box-drawings-double-line-vertical-left-character-ascii-code-185.html

Comment: For example, it shows that 189 in this encoding is "Cent symbol". Just Googline for "Unicode cent symbol" finds a reference like http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A2/index.htm which tells you that it has code 162 in Unicode.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to port code over from another language, and they use the extended ASCII table, so ideally, is there any way you can recommend that we can make the characters to the swift table? Perhaps by finding the unicode or hex?

Comment: Though if I use that method you suggest for black square it gives https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.htm 9632 which overflows when I try unicodescalar?

Comment: Though `9632` won't fit into a `UInt8`, `Unicode.Scalar` also has a version that accepts `Uint32` or `Uint16`. However, those versions can return `nil` when given bad inputs, so you need a `!`: `UnicodeScalar(9632)!` works.